# Reading / parsing text files

Tags: qpython3

I have a script that reads data, process it, and prints an output. The script is not running in the directory where it is saved. I tried to change directory via `OS.chdir`, but still I get the error "file not found". I placed the scripts in the phone storage by drag and drop from my PC.